# Netlify functions unexpected token error while using JSON.parse on post data

Tags: javascript, post, postman, netlify, netlify-function

I am checking out Netlify functions and currently trying to implement POST requests.
This is the code for netlify function:

```
export async function handler(event, context) {

    const bodyParsed = JSON.parse(event.body);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
          bodyParsed: bodyParsed
        })
    };
  }
```

This is the error I get:

```
Function invocation failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 1
```

Now if I return the unparsed event.body using

```
export async function handler(event, context) {

    // const bodyParsed = JSON.parse(event.body);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
          bodyParsed: event.body
        })
    };
  }
```

This is the response I get:

```
{"bodyParsed":"{name: \"Test\"}"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making the request use :

```
{
   "name":"Test"
}
```

instead of :

```
{
   name: "Test"
}
```